# Remove Aelia EU Vat number field from unlogged user in Woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, tax

How can I remove a 3rd Party field for non logged in visitors? It is placed in the billing section, but can't accessed with unset code.

This is rendered in the checkout page:

```html
<p class="form-row aelia_wc_eu_vat_assistant vat_number update_totals_on_change address-field form-row-wide" id="vat_number_field" data-priority="250"><label for="vat_number" class=""><strong>VAT number</strong>&nbsp;<span class="optional">(optional)</span></label><span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><input type="text" class="input-text " name="vat_number" id="vat_number" placeholder="VAT Number" value="" valid="0" aria-describedby="vat_number-description"><span class="description" id="vat_number-description" aria-hidden="true">Only for Retailers: Enter your EU VAT Number (if any). Country prefix is not required.</span></span></p>
```

I don't want to use javascript based solution cause of caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:** You can use the [following dedicated filter hook](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/conditional-eu-vat-number-checkout-field/) to hide that field from unlogged users:

```
add_filter( 'wc_aelia_eu_vat_assistant_show_checkout_field_vat_number', 'hide_vat_field_for_unlogged_users', 10, 2 ); 
function hide_vat_field_for_unlogged_users( $show_field, $is_field_required ) {
     if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) 
         $show_field = false;

     return $show_field
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

> **Note:** Old hook `wc_aelia_eu_vat_assistant_show_vat_field` is obsolete and replaced.

Comment: Thanks. The old hook, that I have used, was the problem. The new is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure which portion of the output you want to hide...
Have your tried with `display:none`?

something like:

`.form-row{
  display:none;
}`

Comment: Would be good to see the encapsulating code just before the `<p>` tag. You may be able to do `display:none` on the entire `div` or `span` 's class directly before the `p` tag

Comment: I could try the css solution. How to do in functions.php in a logged in check?

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
   // your code for logged in user 
} else {
   // your code for logged out user 
}

Comment: I believe most themes will add a `logged-in` class to the body for logged in users.

Comment: you could then use `.logged-in .form-row { display:none}`